# How to connect function to QAction

Tags: qt, qt5

I am not able to execute the function connected to the signal of QAction.

```
 treeView->setContextMenuPolicy(Qt::CustomContextMenu);
connect(treeView, SIGNAL(customContextMenuRequested(const QPoint &)), this, SLOT(onCustomContextMenu(const QPoint &)));

void onCustomContextMenu(const QPoint &point)
 {
     QModelIndex index = treeView->indexAt(point); 
     QMenu* contextMenuTree = new QMenu(this);
     QAction * actionContainer = new QAction("Copy Container", contextMenuTree);
     contextMenuTree->addAction(actionContainer);
     contextMenuTree->exec(treeView->viewport()->mapToGlobal(point));   
     QObject::connect(actionContainer, &QAction::triggered, this, &Renderer::MenuClicked);
 }

 void Renderer::MenuClicked()
 {
     qDebug() << "Menu Clicked";
 }
```

Though i am connection the triggered signal to MenuClicked() function , but the function Does not get invoked.

Comment: Maybe you should call `contextMenuTree->exec(...)` after you set up the connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that by calling `QMenu::exec()` you block the execution until the menu is closed. As a result you establish the connection of your action's signal only when the menu already gone. To solve the problem you should establish the connection rather **before** the menu appears on the screen, i.e.:

```
 [..]
 QObject::connect(actionContainer, &QAction::triggered, this, &Renderer::MenuClicked);
 contextMenuTree->exec(treeView->viewport()->mapToGlobal(point));
```